# "Ничто" или "ни что"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

**Как ничто иное характеризует...**
Как правильно написать «ничто» (слитно или раздельно) и каким правилом это определяется?

Comment: Хорошо бы предложение написать полностью, чтобы смысл был понятен.

Comment: А есть варианты?   
"Сочинение Васи Пупкина, как ничто иное, характеризует состояние образования в Краснолаптинском районе".  
Другого не вижу.
Кастите, там ещё запятая нужна, "как ничто иное" - сравнительный оборот, требующий обособления.

Answer (score -1):

Слитно. По общему правилу о том, что местоимения без "внутреннего" предлога пишутся слитно.

Вообще случай несложный, можно узнать, что именно вызвало сомнение?

Answer (score -1):

Конструкции "не что иное, как" (слово "как" может отсутствовать) и "ничто иное, кроме" (слово "кроме" может отсутствовать) пишутся с отрицательной частицей слитно или раздельно в зависимости от того, сколько отрицаний есть в данном предложении. Одно отрицание - пишется частица "не", и она пишется раздельно. Два отрицания - НИ и слитно. Розенталь: Это был не кто иной, как мой друг. Никто, кроме него, не знал ответа.
    Ваше предложение дано не полностью, но похоже, что здесь одно отрицание,поэтому надо писать: "Как не что иное характеризует..."

Comment: Вы бы хоть с литературой иногда сверялись.
Здесь конструкция "как ничто иное", "как никто иной" а не то, что Вы тут понаписали.

Comment: *Как не что иное* — ужас. Это устойчивые сравнительные обороты: **как ничто иное, как никто другой** и т.п. Как бы Вы написали "просто ты умела ждать, как никто другой."?